# Is XSS in ASP.NET DropDownList possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, xss

I have this in my Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSalutation" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Please chose" Value="" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Mr" Value="Mr"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Mrs" Value="Mrs"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In CS i use:

```
string value = ddlSalutation.SelectedValue;
// ... save value
```

Is it possible that a hacker can change the DropDownList from clientside and send wrong selected values to server? SelectedValue can have different values than "Mr" or "Mrs"?

Answer (score 1):

Xeddon,

According to this post:

[Hacking DropDownList value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349956/hacking-dropdownlist-value)

> Actually you should be able to assume that the dropdown list options have not been changed client side as long as the page has EnableEventValidation = true (which is default although you can disable it per page or in the web.config). If a new value is added to your dropdownlist client side, and a postback occurs an error will occur unless you register this new value for event validation (http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx)

You should definitely be fine.  Should you disable EnableEventValidation, you should be able to manually validate as follows (written as would be in MVC):

```
public ActionResult PageOfGlory(){
    string value = Request.Form["dllSalutation"];
    string[] validSalutations = new string[]{
        "Mr",
        "Ms"
    };
    if(!validSalutations.Contains(value)){
        ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid Salutation");
        return View();
    }
    //Add stuff to database

}
```

I hope this Helps!

Lucas